# Maximising a finite sum of product terms.

Tags: calculus, optimization

For any fixed but arbitrary natural number $n\ge 2$, consider the objective function 
$$ F\left(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\right) = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\sigma_j, $$
where $\{\sigma_j\}_{j=1}^n$ is a given decreasing sequence of real numbers. What is $\textrm{argmax } F$ subject to the following constraints of $\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j = n-2 \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ \lambda_j \in [-1,0)\cup(0,1] \ \ \textrm{ for each $j=1,\ldots,n$.}
\end{align*}
Intuitively, it should be $\lambda_1 = \dots = \lambda_{n-2} = 1$ and $\lambda_{n-1} = \lambda_n = -1$, but I'm not sure how to prove this. I tried Lagrange multiplier which immediately gave me nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we temporarily relax (ignore) the fact that $\lambda_j \neq 0$, $\forall j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$. Let us first solve for $\lambda_n$ as $$\lambda_n = n - 2 - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{\lambda_j}.$$ We also need to impose the bounds $\lambda_n \in [-1,1]$, which result in the additional nontrivial inequality $$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{\lambda_j} \geq n-3.$$

The relaxed problem then reduces to the linear program: $$\begin{align}
\underset{(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_{n-1}) \in [-1,1]^{n-1}}{\max} &\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{\sigma_j \lambda_j} + \left(n - 2 - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{\lambda_j}\right) \sigma_n \right] \\
\text{s.t.} \quad\quad\:& \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{\lambda_j} \geq n-3,
\end{align}$$

which in turn reduces to: $$\begin{align}
n+2 + \underset{(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_{n-1}) \in [-1,1]^{n-1}}{\max} &\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{(\sigma_j - \sigma_n) \lambda_j} \\
\text{s.t.} \quad\quad\:& \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{\lambda_j} \geq n-3,
\end{align}$$

Clearly, in the solution of the above linear program each $\lambda_j$, $j \in \{1,\cdots,n-1\}$, takes the value $\lambda^*_j = +1$, $\forall j \in \{1,\cdots,n-1\}$. Computing the value of $\lambda_n$ using $\lambda^*_n = n - 2 - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{\lambda^*_j}$, we obtain the value $\lambda^*_n = -1$. Since the solution of the relaxed problem $(\lambda^*_1,\cdots,\lambda^*_n)$ is feasible for the original problem (none of the $\lambda$s equal zero), we have that $(\lambda^*_1,\cdots,\lambda^*_n) = (+1,\cdots,+1,-1)$ solves the original problem.